# C# EF Code first One To Many Models

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a DB that looks like this:

```
 Houses
    - HouseId
 Rooms
    - RoomId

 HouseRooms
    - HouseRoomId
    - HouseId
    - RoomId

class House
{
   [Key]
   public virtual int HouseId{ get; set; }


   public DbSet<HouseRoom> Rooms{ get; set; }
 }    

class HouseRoom
```

{
       [Key]
       public virtual int HouseRoomId{ get; set; }

```
   public virtual int HouseId{ get; set; }
   public virtual int RoomId{ get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("RoomId")]
   Public Role RoomInfo {get; set;}
}

class Room
{ 
   [Key] 
   public virtual int RoomId {get; set;}

   public string RoomName {get; set;}
}
```

I just need the House entity/mode to load all the rooms records. Noticed that  the JOIN table has a PK name HouseRoomId but this is not the key that need to match the key in House.  House.HouseId need to match HouseRoom.HouseId.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why/how can a `Room` be in more than 1 `House`?

Comment: it is a RoomType really like Kitchen, BED 1 etc for example,, each house has a floorplan and each floor plan has similar roomtypes.  The example is just to get an idea how to get one to many working in code first.

Comment: Ah, so it's more of a Room template, rather than a room itself, I understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first this is a `many-to-man`y, not `one-to-many`. Second, you need to set the relationship on `ModelCreation` to let the `DbContext` know about this relationship. Also, you need to make your `List<Room>` `virtual` to enable it to load when you need it. 
Please look at this example. 
[Code First Entity Framework Many-to-Many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804175/code-first-entity-framework-many-to-many-relationships)

Also, for the record, you do not need to specify `[key]`, it is already there for you by default

Comment: The virual did it.  I know it was a many to many but I wasnt able to get the one to many loaded.  I think I have it now. Thanks.  Still dont know how it knows how to map the relationships..